# Trying to move text in Flexbox in media query, but it's not working

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So I'm trying to make a mobile version of my site and to do that I'm using a media query, but there is this section of the div where I'm trying to manipulate the text over to the left hand side and I literally cannot do it. In the widescreen site, the content is in a row, but mobile I need it to be in a column, which super easy to do, but for whatever reason I cannot move the content within that div for the life of me.

It should be so simple, but I believe something in the "non-media query" CSS rules is blocking me somewhere, but I can't figure out what or where.

Here's the HTML section that I'm styling.

```
<!-- Footer -->

        <div id="footer-container">
            <div id="footer-text-box">
                <h4 id="footer-header">Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia</h4>
                <p id="footer-text">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo</p>
                <div id="action-box">
                    <img id="action-arrow" src="resources/assets/Icon awesome-arrow-right.png">
                    <a id="action-text" href="#">Lorem call to action</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <img id="footer-image" src="resources/assets/Rectangle 649.png" alt="Family on a walk in nature">
        </div>
```

Here's the normal CSS rules for the section I'm attempting to manipulate.

```
* Footer */

#footer-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    margin-bottom: 130px;
}

#footer-text-box {
    width: 50%;
    padding-top: 60px;
    padding-left: 170px;
    background-color: #F3FFFF;
}

#footer-header {
    font-size: 3em;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #282f57;
}

#footer-text {
    width: 80%;
    line-height: 2;
    color: #282f57;
}

#action-box {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    margin-top: 40px;
}

#action-arrow {
    width: 1.5em;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

#action-text {
    font-size: 0.9em;
    font-weight: 700;
}

#footer-image {
    width: 50%;
}
```

Here's the mobile media query section of the rules.

```
/* Mobile Footer */

#footer-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

#footer-text-box {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    padding-top: 25px;
    background-color: #F3FFFF;
}

#footer-header {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #282f57;
}

#footer-text {
    width: 80%;
    font-size: 0.7em;
    height: 200px;
    line-height: 2;
    color: #282f57;
}

#action-box {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    margin-top: 40px;
}

#action-arrow {
    width: 1.5em;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

#action-text {
    font-size: 0.9em;
    font-weight: 700;
}

#footer-image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
}
```

And here's a quick pic of the thing I'm trying to manipulate. It's the content under the picture that I'm trying to move left.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJeRp.jpg)

I'm trying to do this through Flexbox, so I made the flex-direction of #footer-text-box column and then tried using justify-content: flex-start; (I also tried all the other flex axis to make sure too) to get it over to the left. I'm sure there's some simple reason, but I can't figure it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you doing the media query? Did you make sure if the files are being loaded according to the media query?

Here's my raggedy sandbox that uses your code copied and pasted, except I specified media query within the stylesheet. https://codesandbox.io/s/snowy-https-98ybfl?file=/index.html

If this sandbox represents what you're trying to achieve, then i suspect your media query is wrong.

Comment: Thanks Hiro, finally figured it out. My non-media query rules had left-padding that I didn't adjust in my media query rules. I appreciate the help.